# Txt file that contains only numerical values are not read as numerical objects using read.table

Tags: r

I read a txt file that contains only numerical values with `read.table` , but when I try to perform calculations on the data, like finding the average with `mean()`, it says that the argument is not numerical.

```
dat= read.table("oldfaithful.txt", header= FALSE)
dat= as.numeric(c(dat))
avg= mean(dat)
```

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(dat) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Here is a snippet of the txt.file

```
216  
108  
200  
137  
272  
173  
282  
216  
117  
261 
110  
235  
252  
105  
282
```

This is what dat looks like printed out

```
     V1
1   216
2   108
3   200
4   137
5   272
6   173
7   282
8   216
9   117
10  261
11  110
12  235
13  252
14  105
15  282
```

Comment: If you print `dat` after the first line of the code what does it look like?  Does it look like the text snippet or is that from the original file?

Comment: @hank_044 It looks like the text snippet above, just with row numbers on the left.

Comment: If I'm reading that right, try `avg = mean(dat$V1)`

You need to take the mean of only the data in V1 not the whole data frame.

Comment: @hank_044 That works! Thank you so much. I thought that the data type of the data frame would automatically be numerical since it just contains numerical values, but I guess that's not the case. Thanks again.

Comment: The hint was that `as.numeric(c(dat))` gave you an error before you tried to do the `mean` calculation. A `data.frame` is a `list` of data stored in columns, each of which can contain one type of data - numbers, text, dates etc. It's a bit like asking "*what is the mean of a folder of data, containing some numbers and text and possibly a picture of your cat?*" Which is why R complained and returned `NA`

Comment: No problemn.  You can accept the answer below to close this question for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should probably put that last comment into an answer.

You need to take a mean of only the V1 column in the data frame, not the whole data frame.

I think the last line of code should be

`avg = mean(dat$V1)`